# Cannot forward local port to another local port

Tags: iptables

Trying to forward a local port to another local port 7777 -> 55555

```
# ufw disable
# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i enp58s0f1 --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.47.5:3000
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp58s0f1 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i enp58s0f1 -j ACCEPT

# curl -s -I 192.168.47.5:3000 | head -1
HTTP/1.1 302 Found

# curl 192.168.47.5:7777
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.47.5 port 7777: Connection refused

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp58s0f1/forwarding
1
```

I have also tried port forwarding in ufw, by first reseting ufw rules and adding the following at the beginning of /etc/ufw/before.rules

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 7777 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
COMMIT
```

Here is the output of iptables-save

```
# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4543:2482113]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4543:2482113]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4711:804006]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4781:811782]
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [85:23165]
:INPUT ACCEPT [85:23165]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [183:37649]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [80:5380]
-A PREROUTING -i enp58s0f1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.47.5:3000
-A POSTROUTING -o enp58s0f1 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2058:1070158]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1937:450137]
-A FORWARD -i enp58s0f1 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: The REDIRECT rule is the one to use in this case, as you are not really doing a NAT router implementation. I would add an additional qualifier to the rule and leave ufw out of it: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.47.5 --dport 7777 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`.

Comment: I assume this only has to work from other computers to/from this one. If you want this to work on the same machine, you will also need a rule in the [output chain](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2160104). Do you want the redirection to go to port 55555 or port 3000? Your text and examples do not agree for destination port.

Answer (score 2):

The iptables REDIRECT directive is the appropriate method for same machine port forwarding:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.47.5 --dport 7777 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

As a demonstration and how to verify example I will use a computer at 192.168.111.122 and redirect port 7777 to port 22, where I have sshd listening. So (notice I added a network interface qualifier):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp3s0 -p tcp -d 192.168.111.122 --dport 7777 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22
```

Now, I use another computer at 192.168.111.1 to check it (note: not really trying to telnet, just checking if it can connect):

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ telnet 192.168.111.122 7777
Trying 192.168.111.122...
Connected to 192.168.111.122.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1p1 Ubuntu-5

Invalid SSH identification string.
Connection closed by foreign host.
doug@DOUG-64:~$
```

O.K. that seemed O.K. Try ssh:

```
doug@DOUG-64:~$ ssh -p 7777 192.168.111.122
doug@192.168.111.122's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch) (GNU/Linux 5.5.0-rc6-stock x86_64)
... a bunch deleted ...
Last login: Fri Feb  7 15:32:45 2020 from 192.168.111.1
doug@s18:~$
doug@s18:~$ logout
Connection to 192.168.111.122 closed.
doug@DOUG-64:~$
```

And also check communications at the packet level, during a session, via a tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer) session on 192.168.111.122:

```
doug@s18:~/temp-git-git$ sudo tcpdump -n -nn -tttt -i enp3s0 port 7777
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2020-02-07 15:37:16.480311 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [S], seq 494277163, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 349415894 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:16.480329 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [S.], seq 2825406220, ack 494277164, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2718854230 ecr 349415894,nop,wscale 7], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:16.480600 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 349415894 ecr 2718854230], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:16.486525 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [P.], seq 1:33, ack 1, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2718854236 ecr 349415894], length 32
2020-02-07 15:37:16.486668 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [.], ack 33, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 349415896 ecr 2718854236], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016165 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [P.], seq 1:3, ack 33, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 349416278 ecr 2718854236], length 2
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016175 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [.], ack 3, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2718855766 ecr 349416278], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016262 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [P.], seq 33:67, ack 3, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2718855766 ecr 349416278], length 34
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016408 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [FP.], seq 67:69, ack 3, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2718855766 ecr 349416278], length 2
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016428 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [.], ack 67, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 349416278 ecr 2718855766], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016589 IP 192.168.111.1.45918 > 192.168.111.122.7777: Flags [F.], seq 3, ack 70, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 349416278 ecr 2718855766], length 0
2020-02-07 15:37:18.016600 IP 192.168.111.122.7777 > 192.168.111.1.45918: Flags [.], ack 4, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2718855766 ecr 349416278], length 0
12 packets captured
12 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

doug@s18:~/temp-git-git$ sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 38 packets, 4409 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       4      240 REDIRECT   tcp  --  enp3s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.111.122      tcp dpt:7777 redir ports 22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 40 packets, 4329 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 228 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 2 packets, 228 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
doug@s18:~/temp-git-git$
```

The packet counters are very useful. Note that the PREROUTING path would only be traversed once per connection (I had done it 4 times, when I ran the above command).

If you make a mistake and need to delete your rules and start again, do:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -F
```

to clear the nat table rules. This answer might need to be incorporated into a bigger iptables rule set or UFW context.

EDIT: Oh, by the way:

```
doug@s18:~/temp-git-git$ grep . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/forwarding
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding:0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/forwarding:0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp3s0/forwarding:0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/forwarding:0
doug@s18:~/temp-git-git$ grep . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

Comment: A great answer. Thanks for showing how to test the answer for proper function.